# ASP.NET use of "value' in a function

Tags: c#

Just wondering in the below function

```
        public Dictionary<string, List<TrainingItem>> TrainingItems
    {
        set
        {
            trainingItems = SanitizeTrainingItems(value);

            Results_Repeater.DataSource = trainingItems;
            Results_Repeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

How does the value of (value) get past here and what is it. I mean there is no parameters to function but yet I am still passing a value in function I just don't understand where it comes from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property in C# simulates a data member when in reality it's a set of accessor methods, specifically a `get` accessor and a `set` accessor (unless the property is read-only). In most cases, a property is used to read, write or compute the value of a private field.

A common use for a property would be:

```
private string _firstName;

public int FirstName
{
  get { return _firstName; }
  set { _firstName = value; }
}
```

The `get` and `set` blocks within the property definition represent the accessor method bodies that either read or write the value of `_firstName`. In the `set` accessor, `value` is a contextual keyword representing the parameter of the `set_FirstName` accessor method generated by the compiler.

Without properties, you would have to write these methods yourself, i.e., you'd have a `public string getFirstName();` and a `public void setFirstName(string value);` and you would call each method accordingly. A C# property is just a shortcut and gives you an easy to use mechanism to invoke the correct accessor.

Answer (score 0):

set accessor uses implicit parameter called value, whose type is the type of the property. In the following example, a set accessor is added to the TrainingItems property

When you assign a value to the property, the set accessor is invoked by using an argument that provides the new value.

See it here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04(v=vs.90).aspx